# Google Cardboard with 4.5 inch smartphone

Tags: motorola-moto-g, google-cardboard

Has anyone tried the Google Cardboard (the carton equipment and the relative software from Play Store) with an android device of 4.5 inches like Moto G 1st gen? (I have the LTE - XT1039 version, so, it has gyroscope)

I am asking because I am about to order some of this equipment and I doubt that in less than 5" display the eyes will have the ability to focus and get a clear image...

Comment: I don't think your phone has a gyroscope. Unfortunately, Google Cardboard requires a gyroscope - it might be worth testing the app before ordering any bits of cardboard.

Comment: @keepcalm the moto G 1st gen has a gyroscope

Comment: Ah. It would seem that the LTE model [has a gyroscope](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g_4g-6355.php), while the non-LTE model [does not](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g-5831.php).

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to mention that I have the LTE version, and I tested the application and it works... so, I should have a gyro! Yet my question is mostly oriented on the screen size...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't go for it on a phone with a 720p display, at least 1080p is a must for Virtual Reality. The 4.5 inch phone will work and fit, just pick out the right cardboard. I'd recommend the Moto G3 with 1440p for VR, its actually perfect, your phone is a bit out of date. But if its all you need in a phone, don't bother switching.

Comment: "*at least 1080p is a must for Virtual Reality*" -- can you support this fact with something credible?

Comment: Finally I tested the cardboard with my Moto G and it was working all good... Only the Magnet did not always respond to actions (maybe because the case is made for a bit bigger devices, so it was far from the correct spot). Apart from that, the resolution that jon_woot mentions here is actually a bit of an issue. Because the display gets very close to the eyes and the lenses make pixels even bigger! So Maybe 1080 is a must after all. Overall, the testing experience was pretty good! Gyrospcope working!